# Electron ApplicationMenu only works for last window when you have multiple windows

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm tying to have Multiple windows in my Electron app and each window should have its own applicationMenu. But when I open a new window, the functionalities in application menu such as `reload` and `openDevTools` only works for last window that just opened.
Why this is happening?
Code example:

```
app.on('ready',() => {
  createWindow();
});

ipcMain.on('open-new-window',() => {
  createWindow();
});


function createWindow() {
  const window = new BrowserWindow({
    width:900,
    height:700,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  });
  window.loadUrl('index.html');
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([{
    label: "dev",
    submenu: [{
      label: "Refresh HTML",
      click: () => {
        window.reload();
      }
    }]
  }]);
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
}
```

When i open a new window from `ipcMain`, the reload() function only works in last opened window. Whether i click "Refresh HTML" in the first window or the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one piece of application menu, which (from [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu))

> will be set as each window's top menu

So, when you overwrite it, this is the expected behavior. Let's say

1. You create window #1. `window` variable will refer to #1, thus your application menu will reload that.
2. You create window #2. `window` refer to #2 and you **overwrite** application menu to reload #2 upon click
3. Clicking on #1's menu will reload #2 anyway

---

To resolve this, you can `reload` the current window with [`BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow), this way your `MenuItem`'s function won't depend on the reference of `window`.

Try

```
click: () => {
  BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().reload();
}
```

Comment: The `getFocusedWindow()` fixed my problem. Thanks.